# Value being overwrite when storing user input into a 2D array

Tags: c++

i am quite new to C++, and i trying to program a system, where user are being prompt to select choice. So when user select Option 1, they are prompt to enter 7 value and store into a 2D array. But this is where the storing part issue come in, when user select Option 1 again to enter the 7 value, the value in the array will be overwritten. When user select Option 2, the value that is printed out is a loop of the latest entered value.

So take for example, the first set of 7 value entered is '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' while the second set of value entered when user select Option 1 again is 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g', when i print out the array, the array only display g instead of 7 and g.

Hope if anyone could advice me on this issue.

```
        #include <iostream>     // cin, cout
        #include <fstream>      // ifstream, ofstream
        #include <sstream>      // stringstream
        #include <string>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <iomanip>      // std::setw
        #include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi */
        #include "Printer.h"
        #include <termios.h>    //password masking
        #include <unistd.h>
        using namespace std;


        void displayoption(int);
        void GetInput();
        void DisplayInput();
        void writeUserDatabase();

        struct DataPile
        {
            // to record stock information.
            string x;
            string y;
            string suntype;
            string planet;
            string moons;
            string particulate;
            string plasma;

        };



        const int MAX = 50;
        Printer printer;
        DataPile datapile[MAX][7];






        int main()
        {
             system("clear");
              printer.printName();
        printer.printmainheader(); //display



        int option =-1; //initialise int
            do
            {

            printer.printdisplaymainmenu(); //display menu
            cout<< endl<<"        "<<"Enter Option :";

            cin>>option;
            displayoption(option);

            }while(option!=5);


        }





        void displayoption(int option)
        {
        //option control functions
            switch(option)
            {
            case 1:
            GetInput();

            break;
            case 2:
            printer.printcompute();
            DisplayInput();



            //addstock();
            break;
            case 3:

            break;
            case 4:

            break;
            case 5:

            break;
            case 6:

            break;
            case 9:

            break;
            default:break;
            }
        }




        void GetInput()
        {

            string x;
            string y;
            string suntype;
            string planet;
            string moons;
            string particulate;
            string plasma;


            //getting input from user
            cout<<"";
            getline(cin, x);
            cout<<"Please enter x-ordinate :";
            getline(cin, x);

            cout<<"Please enter y-ordinate :";
            getline(cin, y);

            cout<<"Please enter sun type :";
            getline(cin, suntype);

            cout<<"Please enter no. of earth-like planets :";
            getline(cin, planet);

            cout<<"Please enter no. of earth-like moons :";
            getline(cin, moons);

            cout<<"Please enter ave. particulate density (%-tage) :";
            getline(cin, particulate);

            cout<<"Please enter ave. plasma density (%-tage) :";
            getline(cin, plasma);




            //cout<<x<<" "<<y<<suntype<<planet<<moons<<particulate<<plasma<<endl;


            //storing to array
        for(int i = 1; i <=8; i++){
                    for (int j=1 ; j<=7 ; ++j)  {


            datapile[i][j].x = x;
            datapile[i][j].y = y;
            datapile[i][j].suntype = suntype;
            datapile[i][j].moons = moons;
            datapile[i][j].planet = planet;
            datapile[i][j].particulate = particulate;
            datapile[i][j].plasma = plasma;
            }
        }


            cout<<"     \E[1;29mRecord successfully stored. Going back to main menu\E[0m"<<endl;
         printer.printName();

        }


        void DisplayInput()
        {

            string x;
            string y;
            string suntype;
            string planet;
            string moons;
            string particulate;
            string plasma;


            for (int i=0; i<=1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=6; j++)
            {
                cout << datapile[i][j].plasma<<endl;

            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: Stepping through your code line by line with the debugger, does a much better job on this, than asking on SO.

Comment: TL;DR! Please try to narrow down the code to the parts that causes you the problems. The best is to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop, use += instead of +. This will append the new input onto the string, so you have both the old value and the new one.

```
for(int i = 1; i <=8; i++){
    for (int j=1 ; j<=7 ; ++j)  {
        datapile[i][j].x += x;
        datapile[i][j].y += y;
        datapile[i][j].suntype += suntype;
        datapile[i][j].moons += moons;
        datapile[i][j].planet += planet;
        datapile[i][j].particulate += particulate;
        datapile[i][j].plasma += plasma;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, it solve my issue of retaining the previous added value. I have another qns , currently for my printing, it will print 6 time of the same value. How do i rectified this so that it will only print 1 value on each line . Take for example i enter '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' for first set, 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g' for second set and 'q,q,q,q,q,q,q' for third set, then the output should be like 
    7
    g
    q

instead of 
    7gq
    7gq
    7gq
    7gq
    7gq
    7gq

Comment: In your printing function you only print the value for plasma. Also, I just noticed that in the loop that assigns the values, you start counting at 1. Arrays start at 0, and I'm surprised you didn't break something by going out of bounds and accessing the 8th element, referenced to at [7]. Your printing loop accesses the array properly.